# base64 decode while ignoring brackets

Tags: bash, encryption, base64, sh, decoding

I'm trying to decode a file, which is mostly encoded with base64. What I want to do is to decode the following, while still maintaining the `[_*_]`.

#### example.txt

```
wq9cXyjjg4QpXy/Crwo=
[_NOTBASE64ED_]
aGkgdGhlcmUK
[_CONSTANT_]
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg==
```

Sometimes it'll be in this form

```
aGkgdGhlcmUK[_CONSTANT_]SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg==
```

#### Desired output

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
[_NOTBASE64ED_]
hi there
[_CONSTANT_]
Hello World!
hi there[_CONSTANT_]Hello World!
```

#### Error output

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
4��!:�@�H\�B�8ԓ��[��ܛBbase64: invalid input
```

#### What I've tried

```
base64 -di example.txt
base64 -d example.txt
base64 --wrap=0 -d -i example.txt
```

I tried to individually base64 the `[_*_]` using `grep -o`. Then find and
    replacing them through a weird arrangement with arrays, but I couldn't
    get it to work.
    base64ing it all, then decoding. Results in double base64ed rows.

The file is significantly downsized!
Encoded using `base64 --wrap=0`, while loop, and if/else statement.
The `[_*_]` still need to be there after being decoded.

Comment: Are the base64 blocks always a single line?

Comment: Not always, sometimes its like `wq9cXyjjg4QpXy/Crwo=[_NOTBASE64ED_]aGkgdGhlcmUK`

Comment: How is that different from what you posted in the example?

Comment: Its an example where the base64 blocks on the same line separated by the `[_*_]`, If you mean if one base64 block is super long that it goes onto a new line, or if two are on one line without a separator, then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure someone has a more clever solution than this.  But try this

```
#! /bin/bash

MYTMP1=""
function printInlineB64()
{
    local lines=($(echo $1 | sed -e 's/\[/\n[/g' -e 's/\]/]\n/g'))
    OUTPUT=""
    for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
        MYTMP1=$(base64 -d <<< "$line" 2>/dev/null)
        if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
            OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${line}"
        else
            OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${MYTMP1}"
        fi;
    done
    echo "$OUTPUT"
}

MYTMP2=""
function printB64Line()
{
    local line=$1

    # not fully base64 line
    if [[ ! "$line" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+$ ]]; then 
        printInlineB64 "$line"
        return
    fi;

    # likely base64 line
    MYTMP2=$(base64 -d <<< "$line" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
        echo $line
    else
        echo $MYTMP2
    fi;
}


FILE=$1
if [ -z "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "Please give a file name in argument" 
    exit 1;
fi;

while read line; do
    printB64Line "$line"
done < ${FILE}
```

and here is output

```
$ cat example.txt && echo "==========================" && ./base64.sh example.txt
wq9cXyjjg4QpXy/Crwo=
[_NOTBASE64ED_]
aGkgdGhlcmUK
[_CONSTANT_]
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg==
==========================
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
[_NOTBASE64ED_]
hi there
[_CONSTANT_]
Hello World!

$ cat example2.txt && echo "==========================" && ./base64.sh example2.txt
aGkgdGhlcmUK[_CONSTANT_]SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg==
==========================
hi there[_CONSTANT_]Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop that reads each line and tests whether it's base64 or non-base64, and processes it appropriately.

```
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        \[*\]) echo "$line" ;;
        *) base64 -d <<< "$line" ;;
    esac
done << example.txt
```

Comment: It seems to delete, anything before the `[` in the `wq9cXyjjg4QpXy/Crwo=[_NOTBASE64ED_]aGkgdGhlcmUK` example (which I forgot to add in original post, now its added). Also you forgot a `;;` at the end of `*)`.

Comment: I wrote this answer before you added the edit with `[_NOTBASE64_]` in the middle of a line.

Comment: This would probably be easier in a more powerful language like `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using other languages other than `sh` but here is a solution using `cut`. This would handle the case where there are more than one `[_constant_]` in a line.

```
#!/bin/bash

function decode() {
    local data=""
    local line=$1
    while [[ -n $line ]]; do
          data=$data$(echo $line | cut -d[ -f1 | base64 -d)
          const=$(echo $line | cut -d[ -sf2- | cut -d] -sf1)
          [[ -n $const ]] && data=$data[$const]
          line=$(echo $line | cut -d] -sf2-)
    done
    echo "$data"
}

while read -r line; do
    decode $line
done < example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option, you can say something like:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -lpe '$_ = join("", grep {/^\[/ || chomp($_ = decode_base64($_)), 1} split(/(?=\[)|(?<=\])/))' example.txt
```

The code below is equivalent to the above but is broken down into steps for the explanation purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -MMIME::Base64 -lpe '
    @ary = split(/(?=\[)|(?<=\])/, $_);
    foreach (@ary) {
        if (! /^\[/) {
            chomp($_ = decode_base64($_));
        }
    }
    $_ = join("", @ary);
' example.txt
```

- `-MMIME::Base64` option loads the base64 codec module.
- `-lpe` option makes Perl bahave like AWK to loop over input lines and implicitly handle newlines.
- The regular expression `(?=\[)|(?<=\])` matches the boundary between the base64 block and the maintaining block surrounded by [...].
- The `split` function divides the line into blocks on the boundary and store them in an array.
- Then loop over the array and decode the base64-encoded entry if found.
- Finally merge the substring blocks into a line to print.